# How to just update "rendered" property in JSF

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, facelets

I've got a list of documents and I need to update all at once. 
I did something like this:

```
<ui:repeat id="r_list" value="#{tareaController.controlador.documentosIndexar}" var="documentos" >
```

where `documentosIndexar` is the list of documents. It displays all the documents and its properties fine.
I have two `panelGrid`s, one with the viewer of the document and another one with its information.
At the bottom of the information there's the list of documents.

I need to fill the document's information then select another one without losing the previous one.
I'm trying to update the whole `ui:repeat` and it renders the next document and its information ok but the information of the previous one is lost. 
I also tried doing:

```
<ui:repeat id="r_list">
 <p:panelGrid id="pg_document" rendered="#{tareaController.controlador.documentoSeleccionado.id eq documentos.id}">
 <---- Document components here ---->
 <p:ajax event="rowSelect" update=":f_tarea:r_list:pg_document" listener="#{tareaController.controlador.reemplazarLista(tareaController.documentoSeleccionado)}"/>
</p:panelGrid>
</ui:repeat>
```

All my components, and well, my page is inside a form called `f_tarea`, which is from its template.
When I do the above I update that `panelGrid` from the list, but just that one, and the variable in the rendered condition changed, so all the `panelGrid` dissapear.
Basically, what I want to do is update JUST the rendered condition on all the panelGrids inside the ui:repeat, so one hides and another one is shown without losing the previous one's information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. Excuse me I'm a completly stupid.
I tried doing something I haven't done before: downloading the PrimeFaces manual. On the AjaxBehavior section there's the "process" one which process a component in partial request.
I fixed it just by doing:

```
<p:ajax event="rowSelect" process=":f_tarea:r_list:pg_documento" update=":f_tarea:pg_doc" listener="#{tareaController.controlador.reemplazarLista(tareaController.documentoSeleccionado)}"/>
```

I won't delete the question in case that it helps someone in the future.

Comment: Alternatively you could have wrapped the ui:repeat in a single h:panelGroup and reRendered that single component.

Comment: Yes, I think that I failed hard to explain that. It was the first case and the one that works for me. I just had to add the process property.